# Active Directory - weird behaviour

Tags: c#, active-directory, principalsearcher

I'm trying to get informations (members of groups).

I get every time the message "Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355)"

For getting the groups, it helped to try it just 2 times. The first time doesn't work, but the second time brings me the groups. But for getting the Members of a group, I have no work aroung.

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.178.105:3268", "DC=ibcdev,DC=local", ContextOptions.Negotiate, "Administrator", "123");
        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
        GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

        // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

        // find all matches
        try
        {
            var re2s = srch.FindAll().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        var res = srch.FindAll();
        foreach (Principal found in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(found.SamAccountName);
            var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.Name);
            foreach (var user in group.Members)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user.SamAccountName);
            }
        }
```

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for finding a groups members in a domain:

```
public List<String> GetIDs(string domainName, string groupName)
{
    using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
    using(GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupName))
        return (from x in grp.GetMembers(true).AsParallel() select x.SamAccountName).ToList();
}
```